# Proof of the acceleration formula in tensor notation

Tags: tensor-calculus

From book *"Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces"* by Pavel Grinfeld, Edition 2013 :

> The component $A^{i}(t)$ of acceleration $\mathbf{A}(t)$ of the particle
>   from the preceding exercise is given by
>   \begin{equation}
> A^{i} = \frac{dV^{i}}{dt}+\Gamma_{jk}^{i}V^{j}V^{k}
> \tag{5.71}
> \end{equation}

What is the proof of this equation?

Comment: Hi Pinton. Welcome to Phys.SE. Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE. Why don't you just ask for the proof directly?

Comment: @Qmechanic: 1. Because I thought people rather prefer to refer to a proof instead of writing that here. 2. The question is edited as you said.

Comment: 1. They still can. 2. Better.

Comment: The first term here was called relative acceleration: $\nabla_u\nabla_u n+R(n,u)u=0$, is that the same thing as the acceleration you are asking for?

Comment: @Emil: Honestly, I'm an engineering student with a fairly limited knowledge of tensor calculus. I'm interested in the understanding of how the acceleration in $F=ma$ is written in that tensor notation.

Comment: @Pinton: OK, I don't know either but I could have quoted the theorems in that book if it had been that one.

Comment: Suggest you learn about the geodesic equation if you have not already done so. You eqn you quoted is basically saying "how much acceleration is there in addition to the part associated with free-fall motion."